# Missing type "emulated" for volume-attachment for Oracle Cloud CLI?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Using the GUI there seems to be three different types of volume attachment, ISCSI, paravirtualized and emulated.  However, in the documentation, and the Oracle Cloud CLI, it only offers ISCSI and paravirtualized.

[image]
How do I attach a volume with type emulated through CLI?

*** GUI works, can attach volume with type emulated

```
{
  "attachment-type": "emulated",
  "availability-domain": "wwwl:US-ASHBURN-AD-3",
  "compartment-id": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaambr3uzztoyhweohbzqqdo775h7d3t54zpmzkp4b2cf35vs55ck3a",
  "device": null,
  "display-name": "volumeattachment20181107202740",
  "id": "ocid1.volumeattachment.oc1.iad.abuwcljrto7vk7zd4pcxqqvth3puc6ext33y3kgpmbpb3a6cadgxzquiy2ka",
  "instance-id": "ocid1.instance.oc1.iad.abuwcljrw7lrhtkmthjf7gft2clixhbp7drurv2hszpm2pviarbxcndiyaeq",
  "is-pv-encryption-in-transit-enabled": false,
  "is-read-only": false,
  "lifecycle-state": "ATTACHED",
  "time-created": "2018-11-07T20:27:40.299000+00:00",
  "volume-id": "ocid1.volume.oc1.iad.abuwcljrzuooemejembr7jp3yz7vwd4haq4adjpt67epnanquofiliwzkj5q"
}
```

*** But CLI cannot.

```
root@pc55:/home/oci/userdata# oci compute volume-attachment attach --instance-id ocid1.instance.oc1.iad.abuwcljtp4tobqa2llf42jei7pm3vgrkdlid63hzqcrdlxt77r2bkbayo3qa --volume-id ocid1.volume.oc1.iad.abuwcljt3bycex5ocb7qdwnuci3ch77fiwjz7hezejljcejj3a34q3emlmcq --type emulated
Usage: oci compute volume-attachment attach [OPTIONS]

Error: Invalid value for "--type": invalid choice: emulated. (choose from iscsi, paravirtualized)
```

https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Block/Concepts/overview.htm#attachtype

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct.

```
$ oci --version
2.5.10
```

```
oci compute volume-attachment attach --help
--type [service_determined|emulated|iscsi|paravirtualized]
The type of volume. The only supported value are "iscsi" and "paravir-
tualized". [required]
```

```
$ oci compute volume-attachment attach --type emulated
Usage: oci compute volume-attachment attach [OPTIONS]

Error: Invalid value for "--type": invalid choice: emulated. (choose from iscsi, paravirtualized)
```

I just filed this GitHub issue
https://github.com/oracle/oci-cli/issues/146